# Why jboss service failed to start and why I have 404 error with my rest?

Tags: java, rest, maven, jboss

I am new at restful web services. I wanted to write some code where I want when i write this url `http://localhost:8080/EmployeeService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest/emp/get/101` to get my Employee that i inserted manually. 
This is my Employee class:
k

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
@XmlRootElement(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    public String empID;
    public String name;
    public String email;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }
    public void setEmpID(String empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String gettname() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setname(String firstname) {
        this.name = firstname;
    }
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public Employee(String empID, String firstname, String email) {
        super();
        this.empID = empID;
        this.name = firstname;
        this.email = email;
    }
 public Employee(){}
}
```

This is my rest service:

```
 @Path("/emp")
public class EmployeeService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get/{empID}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathParam("empID") String empID){
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setEmpID("101");
        employee.setname("Mirela");
        employee.setEmail("vujicic.mirela95@gmail.com");
        return employee;
    }
```

this is my web.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>EmployeeService</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is my  pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.com.com</groupId>
  <artifactId>EmployeeService</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.12</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/resteasy-jaxrs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
            <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.19.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>


</project>
```

This is my error in console:

```
  13:03:27,916 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "EmployeeService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined,
    "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"EmployeeService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".PARSE"],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
    }
}
13:03:27,939 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "EmployeeService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war" (runtime-name : "EmployeeService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war")
13:03:27,939 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.default: Address already in use: bind localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
      service jboss.undertow.listener.https: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.listener.https: Address already in use: bind localhost/127.0.0.1:8443
```

EDIT: I have solved problem with jboss. Now my only problem is that I receive 404 when I write url that I wrote above. When I start my index.jsp it works but when i run my rest it giving me 404.

And when i write `http://localhost:8080/EmployeeService-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/rest/emp/get/101` i get 404-not found. Could someone plese help me with these mistakes?

Comment: `Address already in use: bind localhost/127.0.0.1:8080`

Comment: Check if you have started jboss twice

Comment: But my wildfly and tomcat are turned of

Comment: Check if there are java processes running

Comment: I have edited my question, please take a look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configure your rest endpoint? Or where does /rest/ comes from?

Example:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JaxRsActivator extends Application {
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly that I missed. Just one question...when I set this class which extends Application, than I dont have to mapp servlet in web.xml?